# Publish of ASP.Net Core project fails with "DestinationFiles" refers to 1 item(s), and "SourceFiles" refers to 2 item(s)

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Publish of ASP.Net Core project fails with next error:

```
"DestinationFiles" refers to 1 item(s), and "SourceFiles" refers to 2 item(s).
They must have the same number of items.
```

I get an error when I try to publish an ASP.Net Core website to Azure. It builds and runs fine locally. The output prints this:

```
Task "Copy"
        Task Parameter:
    SourceFiles=
        C:\Users\Mikael\Source\Repos\GoMap-Web\src\Web\appsettings.json
                CopyToPublishDirectory=PreserveNewest
                RelativePath=appsettings.json
                TargetPath=appsettings.json
        C:\Users\Mikael\Source\Repos\GoMap-Web\src\Web\appsettings.json
                CopyToPublishDirectory=PreserveNewest
                RelativePath=appsettings.json
                TargetPath=appsettings.json
        Task Parameter:DestinationFiles=C:\Users\Mikael\Source\Repos\GoMap-Web\src\Web\obj\Release\netcoreapp1.0\PublishTemp\PublishOutput\appsettings.json
        Task Parameter:OverwriteReadOnlyFiles=False
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(100,5): Error MSB3094: "DestinationFiles" refers to 1 item(s), and "SourceFiles" refers to 2 item(s). They must have the same number of items.
        Output Item(s): FileWrites=C:\Users\Mikael\Source\Repos\GoMap-Web\src\Web\obj\Release\netcoreapp1.0\PublishTemp\PublishOutput\appsettings.json
        Done executing task "Copy" -- FAILED.
        Done building target "_CopyResolvedFilesToPublishPreserveNewest" in project "Web.csproj" -- FAILED.
Done building project "Web.csproj" -- FAILED.
```

The Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets file (the relevant part, i belive) look like this:

```
    ============================================================
                                        CopyFilesToPublishDirectory

    Copy all build outputs, satellites and other necessary files to the publish directory.
    ============================================================
    -->
  <Target Name="CopyFilesToPublishDirectory"
          DependsOnTargets="_CopyResolvedFilesToPublishPreserveNewest;
                            _CopyResolvedFilesToPublishAlways" />

  <!--
    ============================================================
                                        _CopyResolvedFilesToPublishPreserveNewest

    Copy _ResolvedFileToPublishPreserveNewest items to the publish directory.
    ============================================================
    -->
  <Target Name="_CopyResolvedFilesToPublishPreserveNewest"
          DependsOnTargets="_ComputeResolvedFilesToPublishTypes"
          Inputs="@(_ResolvedFileToPublishPreserveNewest)"
          Outputs="@(_ResolvedFileToPublishPreserveNewest->'$(PublishDir)%(RelativePath)')">

    <!--
        Not using SkipUnchangedFiles="true" because the application may want to change
        one of these files and not have an incremental build replace it.
        -->
    <Copy SourceFiles = "@(_ResolvedFileToPublishPreserveNewest)"
          DestinationFiles="@(_ResolvedFileToPublishPreserveNewest -> '$(PublishDir)%(RelativePath)')"
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
          Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
          RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"
          UseHardlinksIfPossible="$(CreateHardLinksForPublishFilesIfPossible)"
          UseSymboliclinksIfPossible="$(CreateSymbolicLinksForPublishFilesIfPossible)">

      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites"/>

    </Copy>

  </Target>

  <!--
    ============================================================
                                        _CopyResolvedFilesToPublishAlways

    Copy _ResolvedFileToPublishAlways items to the publish directory.
    ============================================================
    -->
  <Target Name="_CopyResolvedFilesToPublishAlways"
          DependsOnTargets="_ComputeResolvedFilesToPublishTypes">

    <!--
        Not using SkipUnchangedFiles="true" because the application may want to change
        one of these files and not have an incremental build replace it.
        -->
    <Copy SourceFiles = "@(_ResolvedFileToPublishAlways)"
          DestinationFiles="@(_ResolvedFileToPublishAlways -> '$(PublishDir)%(RelativePath)')"
          OverwriteReadOnlyFiles="$(OverwriteReadOnlyFiles)"
          Retries="$(CopyRetryCount)"
          RetryDelayMilliseconds="$(CopyRetryDelayMilliseconds)"
          UseHardlinksIfPossible="$(CreateHardLinksForPublishFilesIfPossible)"
          UseSymboliclinksIfPossible="$(CreateSymbolicLinksForPublishFilesIfPossible)">

      <Output TaskParameter="DestinationFiles" ItemName="FileWrites"/>

    </Copy>

  </Target>
```

I have changed the `DestinationFiles="@(_ResolvedFileToPublishPreserveNewest -> '$(PublishDir)%(RelativePath)')"` according to another post here but I still get the same failure, and  I don't know enough about it to find any clear errors, can anyone offer some insight? If this is affected by the bug mentioned in other posts that has no workaround, what alternative ways could I try to publish the app to azure that might work better?

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using? There have been a handful of bugs with this error in VS 2017 RC.2 and earlier. They should be fixed in the latest release candidates.